# Storing a dictionary of Int and Array in NSUserDefaults error

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary, nsuserdefaults

*What I know so far about the subject:*

I understand that there are only certain data types that you can store into NSUserDefaults:

> The NSUserDefaults class provides convenience methods for accessing common types such as `floats`, `doubles`, `integers`, `Booleans`, and `URLs`. A default object must be a property list, that is, an instance of (or for collections a combination of instances of): NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary. If you want to store any other type of object, you should typically archive it to create an instance of NSData.

And I know I can do the following:

```
var cities = [String]()
cities = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("cities") as! NSArray
```

And this is permissible because it casts my cities String array into an NSArray and NSUserDefaults accepts this data type. However, I have a dictionary of an Int and an Array, namely, `var addressDict = Dictionary<Int, Array<String>>()`. I know that NSUserDefaults accepts NSDictionary, NSInteger, and NSArray.

*What I want to know how to do:*

I want to cast my `addressDict` properly so that NSUserDefaults accepts my addressDict. Though, I know that the Dictionary, Array, and Int can be casted into it's NS counterparts as separate entities, but I don't know how to do that altogether as the data type `Dictionary<Int, Array<String>>()`. Any help? For example, I know this is completely wrong but something like `NSDictionary<NSInteger, NSArray<String>>` or something.

Comment: you cannot store dictionary with a `NSNumber` or `Int` as key

Answer (score 2):

To store a dictionary in `NSUserDefaults` you need to convert them to `NSData` first. `NSKeyedArchiver` and `NSKeyedUnarchiver` are perfect for the job. The following example shows how to store your dictionary in `NSUserDefaults` and read it back.

```
    var addressDict = Dictionary<Int, Array<String>>()
    addressDict[3] = ["string1", "string2"] //some example values
    let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(addressDict) //archiving
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    defaults.setObject(data, forKey: "address") //storing
    if let data2 = defaults.objectForKey("address") as? NSData { //reading
        let addressDict2 = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data2) //unarchiving
        print(addressDict2)
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response Adam!

Comment: one question: I think that the code that you've provided was like the "set up" for the NSUserDefaults. How would I go on about actually putting data my dictionary?

Comment: This line creates example data: `addressDict[3] = ["string1", "string2"]`.

Comment: That was a dumb question. Sorry about that.

Comment: I tried the code that you provided and it seems that it is not storing the data permanently. When I do `addressDict2`, it prints the proper data. But after I quit my application, the data doesn't seem to remain in the userdefaults... I'm probably doing something wrong. Any idea what that might be?