# Storing a dictionary in NSUserDefaults and using the data stored.

Tags: ios, swift, nsdictionary, nsuserdefaults

I have been struggling with this problem for 5 days. No joke. Please help! Here is the problem that I am encountering.

***What I know:***

I declared `var addressDict = Dictionary<Int, Array<String>>()` as a global variable. Now, I understand the following code is used to append the data stored in my addressDict and changing the type so that the data can be stored into NSUserDefaults.

```
let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(addressDict) //archiving
self.defaults.setObject(data, forKey: "addressDict") //storing
if let data2 = self.defaults.objectForKey("addressDict") as? NSData { 
     let addressDict2 = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data2)
}
```

Now, every time I run the app, the data that is stored in `addressDict2` gets overwritten by my `addressDict` because when the app starts, there is no data in `addressDict`. So even though I might have appended some data into `addressDict2`, it is getting overwritten by `addressDict` which has no data.

So in order to solve this problem I can run the code above but without the line, `self.defaults.setObject(data, forKey: "addressDict")`, and now, the `addressDict2` is no longer being overwritten by a variable that holds no data, `addressDict`. So the data I appended is stored in `addressDict2`. However, if I do this, I can no longer append new information into `addressDict2` because I don't have `self.defaults.setObject(data, forKey: "addressDict")` any more. I hope you see my dilemma here...

***What I want to know:***

This is what I would like my code to do. I want to be able to append new information into some variable, say `addressDict2`. And when the app starts, I want the data that is in `addressDict2` to be copied into `addressDict`. So this will cause `addressDict` to hold the data that I want it to hold.

***What I've tried:***

In order to try to explain what I meant above, here is some code. Note, **this code does not work**, it's just to, kind of, clarify what I mean and to show if the following code would work, it would solve my problem, I think (please correct me if I am wrong). So in my `viewDidLoad()`, I would have *something like* the following:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("addressDict") != nil {
        if let data2 = defaults.objectForKey("addressDict") as? NSData { 
            addressDict = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data2) //there is an error here that states: "Cannot assign a value of type AnyObject? to a value of type Dictionary<Int, Array<Strings>>
        }
    }
}
```

So now, when I run this code:

```
let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(addressDict) //archiving
self.defaults.setObject(data, forKey: "addressDict") //storing
if let data2 = self.defaults.objectForKey("addressDict") as? NSData { 
     let addressDict2 = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data2)
}
```

The `addressDict` here will no longer be empty and will not overwrite `addressDict2` with empty data. And I will be able to use `addressDict` with all the permanently stored data! And life will be all good. But I have no idea how to do this.

*P.S. I seriously apologize for the length of the question. Thank you for your time!*

Comment: I have already answered your question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32264073/730701). The code I posted compiles and works fine. What you need here is a simple typecast.

Comment: Actually it's not needed to use `NSKeyedUnarchiver` because a dictionary containing `Int`, `String` and `Array` types is property list compliant.

Comment: @Adam, I'm not sure if you answered the question that I posed here (of course, I can very well be incorrect). I think I take it a step further by trying to, as @Rajatp, put it, merge `addressDict` and `addressDict2` so that the data in `addressDict2` can be "put into" `addressDict`.

Answer (score 1):

while saving data into dictionary:

```
let foundationDictionary = NSMutableDictionary(dictionary: StoreDictionary) let dict = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(foundationDictionary) NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(dict, forKey: "yourkey")
```

while using saved data:

```
if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("UserDetails")!=nil {

let dict : NSData = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("yourkey") as! NSData dictionaryName = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(dict) as? NSDictionary
}
```